# textarea attribute wrap=hard does not work on pasted text, any workarounds?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, copy-paste

I have a textarea

```
<textarea id="id-textarea-readme" wrap="hard"></textarea>
```

which works realy fine, until someone writes his text in "notepad" and puts it in there via c&p , the words are wrapped correctly but no "extra" linebreaks are made (which is kind of the purpose of "hard")

Is there any workaround to make this work? any JS or a trick to trigger the linebreaks?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your bug - this seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox, try copy and pasting into this textarea (http://jsfiddle.net/QFXTJ/)

Comment: @acconrad you cant test this issue with pasting alone. The wrap attribute sets behavior for form submission. Say you have the string 0123456789 and the textarea wrappes it between 5 and 6, normaly there is no linebreak involved , with wrap=hard a linebreak is added between 5 and 6 but not if you pasted the string into the form, only if you typed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wrap=hard` attribute is nonstandard and does not work consistently across browsers. Modify the design so that you do not need to rely on such client-side operations. Textarea elements should be expected to yield actual user input, containing line breaks when user actually hit Enter. If you need to split long lines for further processing, do it server-side.

In my tests, IE wraps even in copy and paste. Firefox, on the other hand, introduces hard line breaks only when it wraps at whitespace but not when it wraps inside a “word”, so that for `cols=5`, the input 0123456789 (whether direct or copypaste) gets displayed as two lines but sent as one line, whereas 01234 56789 gets sent as two lines. I would expect to find other browsers incompatibilities as well.

Answer (score 0):

the copy & paste issue probably comes from native OS linebreak/return/newline issues.

you could just listen for change or paste on the textarea DOM element and parse with javascript? that'd be my conceptual guess, here's a generic example in jquery:

```
$("textarea").on("change", function(event){
    $this.replace(/\n\r?/g, '\n');
});
```